# How can I test a react component depending on an external legacy JS library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I have in a component this piece of code

[image]

TagCanvas is defined in the _app.tsx file within a legacy JS script. I need to do like that because if I include it in the component using it doesn't work when the component is rendered again.

[image]

I want to test this component, so I have started rendering the component like this:

```
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react';
import {MusasCloud} from '../../../components/MusasCloud.tsx';

const TagCanvas = jest.fn();
describe('MusasCloud component', () => {
    test('Should render the MusasCloud component', () => {
        render(<MusasCloud musas={[]} />);
        screen.debug();
    });
});
```

I get the html rendered as I expect but I am getting the Canvas error which I would like to avoid.

[image]

As you can see I have tried to mock the TagCanvas function using `jest.fn()` but this is not ding the job I'd expect.

**Question**: How can I avoid this exception when running the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the mock to your `global` in your `setupTest.js` file:

```
global.TagCanvas = {
  Start: () => "this is the mocked implementation"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marek response I have it now working.

It also worked if I do this global definition inside the `beforeAll` process.

[image]

I haven't jest configured to read the `setupTest.js` file. Since I am working in next in this project here is how I added it:

```
//jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
    // Define setupTest file here
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setupTest.js'],
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```